# qBittorrent I/O error when targeting D:\ instead of C:\

Tags: windows-10, qbittorrent

Since I Updated from Win 7 to Win 10 I can't download any torrent to my D: HDD (which is 1TB) but I can download to `C:\` which has Windows 10 installed and is a 128 GB SSD without any issues.

When I select `D:\` as destination target I get loads of I/O errors and torrent never downloads.

[image: http://imgur.com/oMmSe6z]

Running as administrator makes no difference.

qBittorrent version is v3.3.13.

Comment: Either the disk is damaged, or there is a permissions error. Can you use the disk normally?

Comment: I use it daily, and other bittorrent program works. qBittorrent used to work before updating. The disk is ok.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but I had nonstop I/O errors and I tried everything including deleting the D: drive and then recreating it. It turns out it was Windows Defender that was causing all the problems. Simpy toggling it off in it's own settings didn't seem make a difference. However, once I disabled it in the registry and installed a 3rd party antivirus qBittorrent is back to normal. Windows Defender was interfering with other programs, too, such as Adobe Acrobat DC's ability to save files so I'm glad to be rid of it. I'm running Windows 10 Pro.